# How to write specific CSS code for responsive themes that activates depending on the layout of a webpage?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, google-chrome-devtools

this is the [link](http://www.cyberfosters.com) to my website.

Although I've managed to modify much of the CSS of my website, the menubar looks neat in the desktop mode. However when you view my website in mobile view, the menu bar looks ugly as if it is written in plain HTML. I'm trying to figure out what to modify in the CSS using Chrome Developer Tools but I find no luck there. Also, in the menubar, there is a menu called **CS / IT** which has a submenu called **Program Implementations** which shouldn't be appearing by default unless the **CS / IT** is clicked, how do I approach this?

This is the CSS code to the navigation menus :

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on, .menu-toggle {
display: inline;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px)
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu>ul {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
display: inline-block !important;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu>ul {
display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px)
.main-navigation ul {
margin: 0;
text-indent: 0;
}

ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
user agent stylesheetul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
Inherited from div.menu-default_menu-container

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from nav#site-navigation.main-navigation

.main-navigation {
margin-top: 24px;
margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
text-align: center;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from header#masthead.site-header

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from div#page.hfeed.site

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from body.home-page.home.page.page-id-4.page-template.page-template-page-templatesfull-width-php.logged-in.admin-bar.custom-background.siteorigin-panels.siteorigin-panels-home.full-width.custom-font-enabled.single-author.js.myatu_bgm_body.customize-support.su-other-shortcodes-loaded

body.custom-font-enabled {
font-family: "Open Sans",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

body {
font-size: 14px;
font-size: 1rem;
font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
color: #444;
}

body {
line-height: 1;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
www.cyberfosters.com/media="screen"
body {
font-family: "Roboto",arial,sans-serif;
}
Inherited from html

html {
font-size: 87.5%;
}

html {
overflow-y: scroll;
font-size: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: show your code not even your page source is readable

Comment: @Chrys Ugwy: What part of the code do you want? The CSS file is huge!

Comment: Your nav menu media Query codes

Comment: @ChrysUgwu: Here it is! I searched through Google and it came up with Media Queries that display content differently based on window sizes

Comment: i didn't see any thing like this in your previous code. and the media statement is wrong

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do this is via javascript/jquery, tracking click event only with css is impossible

Answer (score 0):

They way I do it is I `display: none;`the original desktop menu when it goes to the mobile layout, and I make another "***Mobile***" menu that `display: none;` in the desktop layout and give it a `display: whatever;` when the layout goes into the smaller ***"Mobile"*** layout. 
So bottom line, 2 different menus for the desktop layout and mobile layout, that switches on and off depending on where you display them.